# Issue with updating of url using ui.router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I, use ui.router and i have the next states hierarchy

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('admin', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '',
            templateUrl: baseUrl + "app/views/_MainLayout.html",
        })
    .state('admin.null', {
        url: '',
    })
        .state('admin.edit-customer', {
            url: "/Account",
            views: {
                "edit-info": {
                    controller: "CustomerEditController",
                    templateUrl: baseUrl + "app/Views/EditCustomer.html"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('admin.add-customer', {
            url: "",
            views: {
                "edit-info": {
                    controller: "CustomerAddController",
                    templateUrl: baseUrl + "app/Views/AddCustomer.html"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('admin.add-student', {
            url: "",
            views: {
                "edit-info": {
                    controller: "StudentAddController",
                    templateUrl: baseUrl + "app/Views/AddStudent.html"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('admin.edit-student', {
            url: "",
            views: {
                "edit-info": {
                    controller: "StudentEditController",
                    templateUrl: baseUrl + "app/Views/EditStudent.html"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('admin.teacher-tool', {
            url: "/TeachingTool",
            views: {
                "edit-info": {
                    controller: "TeacherAssignmentsController",
                    templateUrl: baseUrl + "app/Views/TeacherAssignments.html"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('order', {
            url: "/order",
            templateUrl: baseUrl + "app/views/OrderMain.html",
            controller: 'OrderController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Account');
}])
```

So, when i'm switching between Account and TeachingTool everything works fine, url updates as it should, but when i'm switching between Account and Order or TeachingTool and Order it changes only after second switch to this state.

I debuged and figgured out that url paths changes properly and i thought that url isn't being updated during the digest cycle and i've tried that at the begining of orderController

```
        $timeout(function () {
            $location.absUrl(baseUrl + $state.current.url);
            $location.path($state.current.url);
        }, 200);
```

It did help, but not always, sometimes url is being updated at the first time, but sometimes it isn't. Please lte me know if i'm wrong and help me find the answer

Comment: But the answer here is really simple and easy - just USE the url definition. Do not use empty url. All will start to work as expected

Comment: i have states with url, but not all, in some states im editing only specific view, and i dont need url to be changed, so some states have empty urls. Why is it a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here we are. You have admin state which is abstract. And has no URL. Then any url start with /whatever is considered as child state of admin. But it is not it is another state.

So either you give to admin state URL like `/admin` and then you will have this prepended to all child states or make orders state a child of admin state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for late replying.
I dont have a problem with the values of URL. When I'm switching between logical parts of website I'm directing to the states where URLs have values. There is no problem in working, it switches to the proper state but URLs is not being updated for the first time.

The first approach of yours didn't make anything. Now i'm just having the same problem.The second approach is impossible, because I need to have MainLayout as a base template view because it containes a part which should be present in both logical parts (teachingtool, account)

Comment: Just as a rule, add URL for every abstract state you create. Then, there is no confusion in the router.